# sapply( ) and unused function arguments

Tags: r, sapply

I am new to R and trying to work on one of the homework problems. One family of functions I am practicing to use is the `apply()` family. Specifically, this question asks to use the `sapply()` function to calculate the mean of a vector.

To set up the background a bit. First, here is my prop_peer_pressure function:

Write a function prop peer pressure that takes in the index number of a doctor and a month and returns the proportion of the doctor's contacts who are already prescribing tetracycline by that month. If a doctor has no contacts, your function should return NaN. Check that doctor 37, month 5 returns a proportion of 0.6.

```
prop_peer_pressure <- function(index, month) {
   if (doc.contacts[index] == 0) {
     return(NaN)
   }
   else {
   return(count_peer_pressure(index, month) / doc.contacts[index])
 }
}


prop_peer_pressure(37, 5)
# 37 
# 0.6
```

`adopters()` is another function I wrote which returns the indices of doctors who begin prescribing in month x.

```
adopters(2)
# [1]  10  13  20  56  71  75  76  87 107


sapply(adopters(2), prop_peer_pressure, 2)
# 10     13     20     94     128    132    133    168    200
# 0.0000 0.3333 0.1428 0.0909 0.3333 0.4000 0.3333 0.1666 0.3333
```

This works but I wonder how R knows which "index" number it needs to feed into the "prop_peer_pressure" function? Since my prop_peer_pressure function takes in 2 arguments (index, month)…

```
sapply(adopters(2), prop_peer_pressure, index = adopters(2), month = 2)
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (X[[i]])

Comment: any unnamed argument will revert to their defaults. that said, you're taking the wrong approach to this problem -- look into `by` from `data.table` or `group_by` from `dplyr` for a more typical way of handling grouped operations

Answer (score 3):

### How sapply works

Regarding how sapply works, these three all give the same result:

```
f <- function(x, y) x + y

sapply(1:5, f, 10)
## [1] 11 12 13 14 15

sapply(1:5, function(x) f(x, 10))
## [1] 11 12 13 14 15

c(f(1, 10), f(2, 10), ..., f(5, 10))
## [1] 11 12 13 14 15
```

In each case f is run once for each element of 1:5 using that element as the first argument of f and using 10 as the second argument of f.

### Error in last sapply in question

The last sapply in the question gives an error since it is trying to pass three arguments to the function but the function only takes two arguments. The first argument to prop_peer_pressure comes from successive components of the first argument to sapply and the remaining two arguments to prop_peer_pressure are index= and month= which were specified at the end of the call to sapply.  That is it is trying to run this:

```
c(prop_peer_pressure(10, index = adopters(2), month = 2), 
  prop_peer_pressure(13, index = adopters(2), month = 2), 
  ... etc ...)
```

which is clearly not the intention.